# Is there a way to increase allotted memory for queries in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large table (about 59 millions rows, 7.1 GB) already ordered as i want, and I want to query this table and get a row_number() for each row of the table.
Unfortunately I get the error

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory.

Is there a way to increase allotted memory in BigQuery ?

Here is my query, I don't see how I can simplify it, but if you have any advices I'll take it

```
SELECT
  row_number() over() as rowNumber,
  game,
  app_version,
  event_date,
  user_pseudo_id,
  event_name,
  event_timestamp,
  country,
  platform
FROM
`mediation_time_BASE`
```

Here is the complete error message :

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 146% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): analytic OVER() clauses: 98% other/unattributed: 2%

**Edit:**
the query here represents a list of event starts and ends, and I need to link the start event with its end, so I follow this tip : https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-use-values-from-previous-or-next-rows-in-a-query-in-sql-server/
For that I need to have the rows with row_number() in order to separate this subquery in 2 (event start in one hand and event end in the other), join them and then have one row per event with the start and end of the event, as follow (where subquery represents the query with the row_number()):

```
SELECT
   (case when lead(inter.rowNumber) OVER(ORDER BY inter.rowNumber) - inter.rownumber =1
          then lead(inter.rowNumber) OVER(ORDER BY inter.rowNumber)
          else inter.rownumber end) as rowNumber,
    min(inter_success.rowNumber) as rowNumber_success,
    inter.game,
    inter.app_version,
    inter.event_date,
    inter.user_pseudo_id,
    inter.event_timestamp as event_start,
    min(inter_success.event_timestamp) as event_end,
    inter_success.event_name as results
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM `subquery` where event_name = 'interstitial_fetch') as inter INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM `subquery` where event_name = 'interstitial_fetch_success') as inter_success
            ON inter.rowNumber < inter_success.rowNumber and inter.game= inter_success.game and inter.app_version = inter_success.app_version and inter.user_pseudo_id = inter_success.user_pseudo_id 
GROUP BY inter.rowNumber,inter.game,inter.app_version,inter.event_date,inter.user_pseudo_id,inter.event_timestamp,inter_success.event_name
```

This works fine with a smaller dataset, but doesn't for 59 million rows...

Comment: What happens if you remove `row_number() over() as rowNumber,`?

Comment: it works but my problem is that i need the field row number for each row. This query will be save as a table, and will be called in a more complexe query where i need the row numbers

Comment: Are you able to give a bit more clarity on WHY you need a row number for the next query? Does this represent some ordering or is it just an ID for the row?

Comment: What do you mean "already ordered as i want". Data stored in a relational table is not stored in any given order.

Comment: Does it have to be row number? how about GENERATE_UUID()?

Comment: Generate_UUID() doesn't work for me because i need an integer to join the subquery depending on the value of the row_number() (superior or inferior)

Answer (score 6):

***TL;DR: You don't need to increase the memory for BigQuery.***

In order to answer that you need to understand how BigQuery works. BigQuery relies on executor machines called **slots**. These slots *are all similar in type* and have a limited amount of memory.

Now, many of the operations split the data between multiple slots (like GROUP BY), each slot performs a reduction on a portion of the data and sends the result upwards in the execution tree.

**Some operations must be performed on a single machine** (like SORT and OVER) see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output#use_a_limit_clause_with_large_sorts).
When your data overflows the slot's memory, you experience the described error. Hence, what you really need is to change the slot type to a higher memory machine. That's unfortunately not possible. You will have to follow the query best practices to avoid single slot operations on too much data.

One thing that may help you, is to calculate the OVER() with PARTITIONS, thus each partition will be sent to a different machine. [see this example](https://discourse.looker.com/t/resources-exceeded-during-query-execution-when-building-derived-table-in-bigquery/4414). Another thing that usually helps is to move to STANDARD SQL if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: adding a `partition by ...` resolved this issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

AS per the offical documetation you need to request an increse in the slots for your reservation...

> Maximum concurrent slots per project for on-demand pricing — 2,000
>
> The default number of slots for on-demand queries is shared among all
>   queries in a single project. As a rule, if you're processing less than
>   100 GB of queries at once, you're unlikely to be using all 2,000
>   slots.
>
> To check how many slots you're using, see Monitoring BigQuery using
>   Stackdriver. If you need more than 2,000 slots, contact your sales
>   representative to discuss whether flat-rate pricing meets your needs.

refer to this for slots[1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots), the process for requesting more memory is here[2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots)

Answer (score 1):

- For increasing the BigQuery slots in the project, you may have to contact Google Cloud support or buy [reservations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro).
- I assume you were using the [with clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause) for the subquery which in turns runs out of memory. My proposed solution is to create a expiring table that will expire in a few days automatically with the syntax of

  *OPTIONS(expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 DAY))*
- With this approach, I imagine inserting the 59 million rows of query result into a expiring table will use a lot less slots. Replace your subsequent subquery with the expiring table name.
- To avoid being billed for the expiring table, you may delete it after all the dependent queries are executed.