# Bigquery all of the sudden Resources exceeded

Tags: google-bigquery

I get the following error: *Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 126% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): JOIN operations: 99% other/unattributed: 1%* error when I use the following query.

The error only comes up when I add the `ifnull(sum(self_join.x.),0)` lines to the query, showing that they are the cause of the memory problems. These problems occured today all of the sudden. I allready tried to make the dataset `XXXX.TST_202` much smaller than when it ran before but still the error occur, does anybody have any idea why this problem all of the sudden comes up? Could it be that the company lowered our memory limit?

```
 SELECT 
        original.x1
        ,original.x2
        ,original.x3
        ,original.x4
        ,original.x5
        ,original.x6
        ,original.x6
        , ifnull(sum(self_join.x1),0) as previous_x1
        , ifnull(sum(self_join.x2),0) as previous_x2
        , ifnull(sum(self_join.x3),0) as previous_x3
        , ifnull(sum(self_join.x4),0) as previous_x4
    FROM `XXXX.TST_202` original
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
        y1, y2, y3, y4, x1, x2, x3, x4
        FROM `XXXX.TST_202` 
    ) AS self_join
    ON self_join.y1 = original.y1 
    and self_join.y2 = original.y2 
    and self_join.y3 < original.y3
    and self_join.y4 = original.y4
    WHERE original.y1 BETWEEN  REPLACE(CAST(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 day) AS STRING), '-', '') AND REPLACE(CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS STRING), '-', '')
    group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has to do with BigQuery [Slots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots) reaching its limits

"A BigQuery slot is a virtual CPU used by BigQuery to execute SQL queries. During the query execution, BigQuery automatically calculates how many slots a query requires, depending on the query size and complexity."

In general opitmisation of tables by a [Partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) and [clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) helps to resolve this issue. As explained with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60642883/19378826).